# <PHP> error in code, can't seem to find the issue

Tags: php

i'm currently setting up a website, where i send the users that register an activation email.
when they click the email it'll redirect them with an URL like: **webpagehere?Key=123456789**

now i want to get the value from key, but i can't retrieve it somehow.
currently im using:

```
if( isset( $_GET['Key'] )) {
$SCode = $_GET['Key'];  
}
```

and i want to input $SCode into my database using my querys.

the only problem is, i dont seem to get any value into $SCode

after i fill in the info, and submit my form, i get

Notice: Undefined index: Ref in C:\wamp\www\productie\verify.php on line 10

on line 10 is the  code

anybody care to help me out?

**edit: i put all my execute code that loads after submitting the register form into pastebin.com
http://pastebin.com/6Sdje0V9**

Comment: Post some code, and we can help you.

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive - are you sure that that K in Key is capital in the URL you are calling is also capital?

Comment: yes, the K is in capital in the URL aswell, i double checked that :)

Comment: Head to pastebin.com, paste in the **entire** file, and post a comment here with the URL. Something else is going on here...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6Sdje0V9 is the code, i really appreciate all your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ay ay ay.
your error message

> Notice: Undefined index: Ref in C:\wamp\www\productie\verify.php on line 10

your code should be

> ```
>   if( isset( $_GET['Ref'] )) {
>     $SCode = $_GET['Ref']; 
>       echo "SCODE IS => " . $SCode;
>     }
> ```

Ref != ref

didn't someone already bring up case sensitivity in one of their comments?

Comment: i tried both :) ref and Ref aswell as in the file as on the url itself :) still nothing :(

Comment: well, the simplest way to check if anything's coming over the wire is to var_dump($_GET); and see if anything's in there.

Comment: how do i do that? i'm still new to PHP, only started a week ago :)

Comment: put it at the top of the file and look at the output that shows up on the screen after you enter the URL into the browser.

Comment: when i add that to my register page on top i get: array
  'Ref' => string '1234567' (length=7)  when i submit the form tough, i keep getting the error when i echo the $ref value...

Comment: see my edit.  you should be checking for $_GET['Ref'] then.  echo it (for debugging purposes) to be sure it got assigned.

Comment: i put in the edit code, but i get no echo, if i change it to        if( isset( $_GET['Ref'] )) {
        $SCode = $_GET['Ref']; 
          echo "SCODE IS => " . $SCode;
        }
  else { echo "nothing";} then i do get "nothing" echo'd

Comment: I'm confused about one thing though...if you are submitting a form, where does the Ref come from?  You can't really mix GET/POST.  From the original post, you where just trying to get Key, via URL query string.  Now we are on a registration page mixing form submission and query string?  Something's not adding up... please specifically state the intent of this in your post.  This is getting too long...

Comment: @Christoph let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1394/discussion-between-thescientist-and-christoph)

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to access the value at (assuming the variable is actually named key, if not replace it with what you called it):

```
$_GET['key']
```

In older versions of PHP there was something called register_globals which would have allowed you to access the variable right at `$key`, but it was an insane security hole so it's now (thank goodness) disabled by default, so you'll have to use the array at `$_GET`...

Comment: i tried $key = $_GET['key'] but it doesnt get my the variable :(

Comment: it's empty when i look in my database :(

Comment: Lol database now.. Love new users

Comment: ...did you try simply `echo`ing it to the screen to show the value? check your SQL? Go back and edit your question and tell us *exactly* what you are trying to do...

Comment: i only get an error, i edited my opening post and hope its a bit clearer right now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $_GET['key'];
```

Will have the value you seek.